# AJAX Display Images

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have a page that shows whether a user has paid or not. If they haven't paid I need to show them an image of a big red `X` and display a payment button, and if they have paid display a big green check. I know how to do the code for the php script, lets call it `pay.php`, but I need to iron out the logic for the main page's ajax. So I'm thinking something like this:

```
<div id="payment">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="pay_text></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(<?php echo $is_logged_in; ?>) {
        $('#payment').load(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data: $this.serialize(), // get the form data
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: "Scripts/pay.php", // the file to call
                complete: function(data) {
                    if(data=="Yes") {
                        $('#image') //do some jquery to make the correct image display here
                        $('#pay_text').text("Yah you paid");
                    } else {
                        $('#image') //do some jquery to make the correct image display here
                        $('#pay_text').text("Sorry you didn't pay");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

So basically the script would echo back `yes` or `no`. And I only want to evaluate this load after the user has logged in (i need to see if that specific user paid). So is my logic write or am I way off?

Comment: You don't need Load and Ajax.. Are you actually trying to load something inside your #payment element?  If not you can get rid of that and just do the ajax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should'nt use `load` that way, and there really is no need for it.

Your PHP variable `$is_logged_in` would of course have to be `true` before the ajax function will run, and returning `true` or `false` is usually the way to go with code, not returning `yes` or `no`, and if `data` is either `true` or `false` you can stick it right in the if statement, no fuzz!

As for sending form data with the ajax function, what form? And what is `$this`?

You'll have to figure out if the user paid or not on the serverside, and you don't really need any data from the client to do that, all you need to do is check your database or whatever it is you're using to see if that user paid, and return `true` or `false`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(<?php echo $is_logged_in; ?>) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/pay.php"
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#image').css('background', 'url(/yes.png)');
                    $('#pay_text').text("Yah you paid");
                }else{
                    $('#image').css('background', 'url(/no.png)');
                    $('#pay_text').text("Sorry you didn't pay");
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>​​​​​​​​​
```